# Hiding input fields with type='hidden' vs using a class with display:none

Tags: html, security, browser, client

There are several hidden form fields on my pages that are used for passing data to server side. For debugging purposes, I feel it easier to hide all eligible input fields by just making them all a part of hidden class than setting the type=hidden attribute on each input field.

Whenever I need to debug I could easily modify that class attribute to enter debug mode. Ofcourse both the approaches work in hiding the input fields but I am not sure as to why  this approach(hiding via class) isn't much widely used in real life. Can you throw some light on what should be preferred approach ?

Comment: to those voting to close please also indicate why this is not a good question or atleast how to improve my question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`<input type="hidden">` won't trigger input validation, auto completion, and other user interaction related events. It's designed to save raw data, without user's direct input.

But a `<input type="text">`, visually hidden, are still going to be considered as a user interaction component. And on some devices enabled visual aid, it will serve as not hidden, and cannot provide the consistency you expected. That's why it's not preferred to do so.

Eg. a `<input type="hidden">` won't auto complete it self, or preserve the inputted data before refreshing a page, or prevent the form from being submitted for a failed type validation can't even be seen.

Answer (score 9):

The CSS approach is bad for usability, and accessibility. Think of someone with CSS disabled (very old mobile phones, people with a screen reader), they won't render your CSS as you might expect, and the input with all of its glory would be displayed to the user.

A hidden input should be used for **implied user input**, meaning, input that would come from the user, but is implied and does not need to be manually entered.

Your question falls more onto the `type="hidden"` approach.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using `<input type="hidden" />` because it is the standard way of HTML to hold a user's input value. If you use another attribute for `type` and hide it with `css`, one problem may arise is that when the css fails to load, the `input control` will show up.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about the best approach for debugging form fields. I recommend keeping them as type='hidden' in your HTML. This is best for you, for your users and for semantic interpretation of the page.

Instead, use a tool like the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to do your debugging. This will let you easily see the values of your hidden fields.